# Adding user defined functions to a simple calculator YACC

Tags: function, calculator, yacc, lex

I've been searching all over the internet for a comprehensible example to how you can define and call a function in a simple calculator interpreter. Maybe I've found the answer but since I'm not familiar with YACC I couldn't see it.

So the question is, how do you set up a symbol table for user defined functions and how do you store/call these functions in a calculator interpreter?

I'm basically looking to achieve something like this:

```
def sum(a,b) { a + b }

sum(5,5)
```

result:

```
10
```

Any pointers or examples would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's definitely diving in to the concepts required to interpret (or compile) a programming language, which makes it difficult to provide an answer in a format suitable for StackOverflow. Here's a quick outline:

1. You need a symbol table which can hold both functions and variables. Or two symbol tables. In the first case, the mapped value will be some kind of variant type, such as a discriminated union; you might need that anyway if you have more than one type of variable. In the second case, you can use a specific type for the mapped value of function names. I'd go for the first option, because it allows functions to be first-class objects.
2. You need some kind of type which represents the "value" of a function definition. The obvious type is the [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST) of an expression (or a program), and doing that will generally simplify your code so I'd highly recommend it. That means that the calculator/parser will not actually evaluate `5+5` (even if that is the literal input) or `a+b`, but rather will return an AST to whoever called the parser. Consequently, you will need:
3. A function which can evaluate an AST. That's usually straightforward to write, since it's just a depth-first tree walk. But now you need to worry about [variable scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) because when you do evaluate they body of your function `sum`, you probably want to only locally set the values of the parameters.

If you manage all that, you will have gone several steps beyond the usual "let's build a calculator with flex and bison" project, and I definitely encourage you to do so. You may want to take a look at the classic text [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) (Abelson & Sussman, 1996; often referred to simply as SICP).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I guess I gotta buckle up for some serious concepts and your pointers seem helpful